# struts2 value stack scope

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, valuestack

I am developing an application in Struts2 framework. I have used model driven approach in the action classes and I am using those model objects in my JSP to display the intended information. These information are stored in the database. So ideally for every request the flow should go from presentation layer to dao layer and bring the information set it to the model objects and then model object is being used to show that information with the help of property tag. Now when I make one request, jsp shows me the information. After this, even if I delete that information from the database still the same request again shows me the same information(though the information is no more in database). It seems the values on `valueStack` is in session scope. But I want them to be in requested scope.

Comment: Post the code, it's unclear how did you put it into the session.

Comment: @Mayank after deleting record from database its not there! Right ??....but its there in JSP because you haven't  updated Model Or Deleted the Model from List or something ...bla bla bla

Comment: Could it be just browser cache?